# Is there any way to bind to a live wallpaper service?

Tags: android, service, live-wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper which has some resources loaded and set up inside my custom *WallpaperService* class. Something like this:

```
class MyLiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {
    MyResources sharedResources;

    public onCreate() {
       // set up some resources
    }

    public MyResources getSharedResources() {
        return sharedResources;
    }
}
```

And I also have a preferences activity for this live wallpaper that is properly set in *res/xml/wallpaper.xml*. What I want is to somehow provide this *PreferencesActivity* an access to these shared resources. I know I could make them public static fields but I prefer a cleaner solution - if only there was a way to bind to wallpaper service (so I could access a MyLiveWallpaperService instance) that would be rly cool.

In the end activity and service are in the same process in my case, so something described as [accessing local service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) in dev guide should work, **BUT** *WallpaperService* docs [discourage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29) overriding onBind() method which makes this idea impossible to come true.

Is there any other way? :)

Answer (score 0):

i also wanted to bind to a live wallpaper service but is not possible. If you want to pass data to a wallpaper service maybe you can use SharedPreferences as a  alternative to use static field